# Sticky footer inside a wrapper with a page border

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

**Update: here's a pen:** http://codepen.io/isiahmeadows/pen/RrjOEZ?editors=110

I'm aiming for a traditional sticky footer, responsive, that's something like this:

```
* *  | header  |  * *
* *  | ------- |  * *
* *  | content |  * *
* *  |         |  * *
* *  |         |  * *
* *  |         |  * *
* *  | ------- |  * *
* *  | footer  |  * *
```

The sides are colored, and there's the traditional header and footer, but I'm having trouble getting the sticky footer to actually be contained within the wrapper. Here's my relevant Jade and Stylus (using those instead of HTML/CSS, but I'm okay with HTML/CSS answers).

```
//- Jade
#content
    #header //- header stuff
    #body //- body block
    #license: div
        footer
            small
                //- license stuff
```

```
// Stylus
body
    font-family "Arial", sans-serif
    background-color page-border-color
    color black

#content
    background-color white
    max-width 1200px
    width 90%
    height 100%
    margin 0 auto
    padding 1em 1.5em 0 1.5em
    side border 1px solid #888

#header
    .separator
        margin-top -0.25em

        &::after
            content "|"
            font-size 1.25em
            color border-color

#license
    position absolute
    right 0
    bottom 0
    left 0

    div
        rule top 0.5em

    footer
        margin 1em auto
        text-align center
        width-scale 50% 200px 600px
```

Google doesn't seem to be my friend here, since every possible solution I've tried (totaling about half a dozen distinct methods) doesn't stretch the main wrapper to the bottom behind the #license div. Most of the others used absolute positioning, which won't work well if I want to keep my site responsive. Every one of those solutions, including the one I've attempted above, stretches the bottom to fill the viewpoint width and/or results in something like this:

```
* *  | header  |  * *
* *  | ------- |  * *
* *  | content |  * *
* *  |         |  * *
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * *  -------  * * *  <-- Background color behind footer
* * *  footer   * * *
```

Not something I want. Any ideas how to fix this without absolute positioning, preferably without JavaScript?

Comment: Try editing height:100% to height:auto for container

Comment: @MathiasHaugsbø Doesn't work. Same result as most.